# Use boolean to set value of 2d array in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, boolean

I am doing the airline reservation project and mine asks that when a seat is taken that it displays a `*` and when it is empty it displays a `#`. I wanted to set the array as a boolean so if it is false its a `#` and if true its a `*`. Will this work or am I way off? Is there an easier way to do this?

```
bool seatFirst[4][3];
if(seatFirst == true)
    cout << "*" << endl;
else
    cout << "#";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't work, because you are testing the array itself, which will evaluate to true. You need to test individual elements. There is also no need to check a `bool` against `true`, you can just do `if (theBool). Finally, you cannot append`endl`; to a string literal, you need to "stream" it with an`operator<<`.

Here, the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#C.2B.2B) is used to make the code more concise:

```
std::cout << (seatFirst[i][j] ? "*" : "#") << std::endl;
```

Comment: Do i need to intiate a count for the [i][j] so it knows which one its working with or is this just setting the boolean values? Thank you for your response and please bear with my newbness, I am only 8 weeks into my first programming class.

Comment: @LarryTinnonJr. this is not setting anything. It assumes you have set the values somewhere, and that you know which seat you want to enquire about. It is a repaired version of what you posted in your question, which looks like an attempt to print `*` or `#` to standard output depending on whether a seat is taken or not.